Add multiple rows to excel table from power bi
I am trying to add multiple rows to an excel table using a power bi "run query against dataset" action.
The flow runs as follows

Run query against data set
Parse JSON - this could be where the issue is
Add row into excel table - this could also have issues

This is the Parse JSON code
{
    "type": "object",
    "items": {
        "type": "array",
        "properties": {
            "['Learning Plan'[Apprentice Email]": {
                "type": "string"
            },             
            "['Learning Plan'[Apprentice Name]": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}

I am using the following expression in the Apprentice Email field to try and grab that item but I keep getting "expression invalid"
if(contains(item(), ‘['Learning Plan'[Apprentice Email]’ ), item()’['Learning Plan'[Apprentice Email]’ ,’’)


Here's my flow diargram:

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Double check your quotes in your expression. It appears you have stylized single quotes (‘ and ’) in your expression, which are not treated the same as a typical single quote (') by the interpreter. These stylized quotes often get accidentally included when you copy code from a word processor like Microsoft Word.
Replace your expression with the following and it might work:
if(contains(item(), "['Learning Plan'[Apprentice Email]" ), item()"['Learning Plan'[Apprentice Email]" ,'')

You may also notice I replaced some of the quotes with double quotes ("). Generally, you cannot nest single quotes within single-quoted strings unless they are escaped. However, it's often easier to nest single quotes inside double quotes.
Please note that I did not check that this new expression will work. I am only pointing out some issues that are definitely causing problems.
